# how to pass windows forms textbox input to powershell module function

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

Following is the abstract view of what i am trying to do; all of these scripts are in the same folder

```
# Windows Form script called gui.ps1

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(891, 414)
$Form.text = "Form"
$Form.TopMost = $false

$Label1 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label1.text = "Enter the Text : "
$Label1.AutoSize = $true
$Label1.width = 25
$Label1.height = 10
$Label1.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(39, 188)
$Label1.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif', 10)

$text_box = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$text_box.multiline = $false
$text_box.width = 695
$text_box.height = 20
$text_box.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(144, 183)
$text_box.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif', 10)

$Button1 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button1.text = "Submit"
$Button1.width = 106
$Button1.height = 30
$Button1.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(386, 239)
$Button1.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif', 10)

$Form.controls.AddRange(@($Label1, $text_box, $Button1))

$Button1.Add_Click({ txtInput })           # txtInput is defined in module.
```

```
# module called demo.psm1 

function txtInput
{
    $txt = $text_box.Text
    Write-Host $txt
}
```

```
# execute.ps1

Import-Module -Name $PSScriptRoot\demo.psm1

Set-Location $PSScriptRoot

. .\gui.ps1        # dot sourcing

[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```

When I run the execute.ps1 script, the form is showing. But when I click the Button1, textbox input is not showing in the powershell.
Tried to define the 'txt' variable in the module as $global:txt = $text_box.Text. It did not work.

How can I get this to work ?

Comment: take away the space before the opening bracket: `$Button1.Add_Click({..})`

Comment: did it. not working.

Comment: Do you get an error message? Did you change anything in the `demo.psm1` and not restart your PowerShell?

Comment: no error  messages were shown. when i run the script, gui shows up and i entered some texts into the box and clicked submit button. but nothing is showing in the powershell console. the function in the module is supposed to take the input from the text box and display it when submit button is pressed.